# Where I can find a list of Wordpress security risks?

Tags: hacked

I'm working on one project where I need to find a list of different security risks or malicious codes which were used by hackers nowadays or in past.

I can go and search one by one, but it will take a lot of time to gather a decent list of it.

So, does anyone know where should I search or if someone gathered something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [WPScan Vulnerability Database](https://wpvulndb.com/)

The vulnerabilities are classified in 'Wordpress', 'Plugins' and 'Themes' at the top bar, from 2014 on.

Cheers